# AEM Page Image in Page Properties Doesn't Apply a sling:resourceType

Tags: aem

Using Adobe Experience Manager 5.6.1 (AEM) (Formerly CQ5) I am trying to create a new tab similar to the Image tab in Page Properties.  It would be titled "Logo".

I basically just copied the Image tab to create a logo tab and renamed the paths to reflect the logo purpose. For instance, I set the `fileReferenceParamater` to `./logo/fileReference` and `requestSuffix` to `/logo.img.png`.

When I edit the properties, I can drag an image into the tab just as I can with the "Image" tab, however, the image never appears there.  I am guessing this is because the default image handler is not picking up the request.  The error is:

> Cannot serve request to
>   /content/my-site/home-page/en_us/jcr:content/logo.img.png in
>   org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

When I looked at the content node there was no `sling:resourceType`.  When I added a resource type of `foundation/components/adaptiveimage` then it worked.  However, I noticed that the "Image" node didn't have a `sling:resourceType`.  I guess the `img.png.java` servlet in the foundation page is handling that request.

I tried creating a `logo.img.png.jsp` file in my page component to handle the request, but that didn't seem to work.

How can I get AEM to either add the `sling:resourceType` or to handle the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the similar problem and I found a simpler way to resolve. All you need to do is to add a `hidden` xtype under the your `logo` image as below:

```
<yourlogo
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    <-- other properties -->
    xtype="html5smartimage">

    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <resType
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
            name="./logo/sling:resourceType"
            value="foundation/components/image"
            xtype="hidden"/>
    </items>

</yourlogo>
```

Comment: I am interested in this approach.  I will give it a try and select this as the answer if it works.

Comment: This worked and seems like the cleanest, most native way of accomplishing the goal. FWIW, one thing that was throwing me off was a JavaScript bug around the "fallbackUrl" in Chrome. The default renditionSuffix for the first image is "/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1280.1280", which if not present falls back to the "/_jcr_content/renditions/original". However, in Chrome the fallback fails. (CQ 5.6.1) Using FF or adding renditionSuffix = "/_jcr_content/renditions/original" to the overlaid adaptiveimage dialog image, worked around that issue.

Comment: This approach works for me. How do I handle this for touch UI?

Comment: @saravana Long time no use CQ5, so don't know how to handle that for touch UI!

Comment: @TuanDang, I found how to do this for touch ui as well. Parallel to image node, need to create resType node with hidden property and value set.

<image/>
                                    <resType
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                        name="./image/sling:resourceType"
                                        value="foundation/components/image"/>

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some time experimenting, this is what I ended up doing to get this to work.  If there is an easier way, I would be happy to know it.

**First**, I copied the `/libs/foundation/components/page/img.png.java` file and added it to my compiled package with some modifications.

```
@SlingServlet(
        resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default",
        selectors = "imgnode",
        extensions = {"png","jpg","jpeg","gif"},
        methods = "GET"
)
public class SimpleImageServlet extends AbstractImageServlet {
```

Where `img.png.java` had the following line:

```
Image image = new Image(c.resource, "image");
```

I changed it to:

```
Image image = new Image(c.resource);
```

This relies on SCR annotations to generate the OSGi configuration so that this servlet will handle image requests having the `imgnode` selector. Instead of looking for a child `image` node it just expects the current resource to be an image.

**Second**, I added a component to the body.jsp overlay of the page component, like so.

```
<cq:include path="logo" resourceType="/apps/my-site/components/logo" />
```

This maps the logo path to a component for rendering.

**Third**, within the logo.jsp on the component I set the selector to `imgnode` rather than `img`.

```
Image img = new Image(resourcePage, "logo");
img.setSelector("imgnode");
```

I believe this step would be similar if the adaptiveimage were overlayed.  You just need to render out URLs that include the `imgnode` selector.

**Fourth**, I setup the logo image dialog tab in page properties to use the expected `requestSuffix` and set the other properties to point to the logo sub-node.

Examples:

```
requestSuffix = "/logo.imgnode.png"
fileReferenceParameter = "./logo/fileReference"
```

**Fifth**, I made sure that the image dialog tab for the `/apps/my-site/components/logo` component pointed to itself.

Examples:

```
requestSuffix = ".imgnode.png"
fileReferenceParameter = "./fileReference"
```

Now whether it is in page properties, component editing, or final rendering, the image is handled appropriately.

Comment: I am wondering if you have had a chance to take a look at my answer below? Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a nuisance with using the image widget controls--only the image component nicely handles the data, and the servlet that handles ".img" is tied to the image component resourceType.

the easiest thing is to just use the value of the fileReference property instead of referencing the image as part of the page. since you're using assets from DAM, this is a reasonable approach.

this doesn't address the issue with a user uploading an image directly. i wanted to suggest having a hidden field like "./logo/sling:resourceType", but testing that locally resulted in an error when trying to save the dialog.

another approach is the following:

```
<sling:include resourceType="foundation/components/adaptiveimage" resource="${resource.path}/logo" />
```

(assuming `resource` is jcr:content). this is effectively the same as adding a sling:resourceType, but there are at least 2 downsides:

1. the image becomes authorable at that point as opposed to in the dialog
2. this method only works for rendering a normal  tag. it won't work for any sort of background image

Comment: Thanks for this helpful information. However, I couldn't get this working for both the in-page editing and the page properties. I tried changing `resource` to `path` and that kinda worked in the page, but I couldn't get the component and page dialogs working in concert.