# why do we need to inherit parbase component for all image components

Tags: aem

According to Adobe's documentation for AEM development, we should inherit parbase component for all image rendering components.
Could anyone please share a rationale behind this necessity? and also Could anyone please point to other alternatives to this (if any)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of Parbase component:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400388/what-is-the-use-of-parbase-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a loo at the Adobe AEM Forum Post:- **http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__3vh2-why_do_we_needtoin.html**

Parbase is just a component from which you extend to get some OOTB functionality.

If I can say in technical language, Parbase is a key component as it allows components to inherit attributes from other components, similar to subclasses in object oriented languages such as Java.

For example, when you open the /libs/foundation/components/text node in the CRX Explorer, you see that it has a property named sling:resourceSuperType, which references the parbase component. The parbase here defines tree scripts to render images, titles, and so on, so that all components subclassed from this parbase can use this script.

While creating your own components, you don't need to add 'parbase' as a supertype, unless your components need to be enabled with drag-drop in a parsys.

AFAIK, the parbase component is never used explicitly, but only facilitates the rendering of a component when added in the Parsys.

"The parbase allows components to inherit attributes from other components"

If you check under "/libs/foundation/components", most of the authorable and draggable components have 'parbase' set as their 'sling:resourceSuperType' so that they can inherit the image and text rendering properties when added to a Paragraph system (Parsys Component).

Documentation link:- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/default_components/designmode.html#parbase

I hope this helps.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni

Answer (score 0):

parbase has a img.GET.java file which will handle all requests that have the 'img' selector. If you call 'component.img.png' the image will be handled. If you don't inherit from parbase you'd have two options: implement the img.GET.java for your component or save in the component the resource type for the image. I usually do the later when I have a component which store the image data in sub-nodes.

If I want to save the image in a sub-node called image, this is what I add in dialog.xml:

```
        <image
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            cropParameter="./image/imageCrop"
            ddGroups="[media]"
            fileNameParameter="./image/fileName"
            fileReferenceParameter="./image/fileReference"
            mapParameter="./image/imageMap"
            name="./image/file"
            requestSuffix="/image.img.png"
            rotateParameter="./image/imageRotate"
            title="Image"
            xtype="html5smartimage">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <restype
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./image/sling:resourceType"
                    value="/libs/foundation/components/image"
                    xtype="hidden"/>
            </items>
        </image>
```

this approach is discussed, for example, here: [AEM Page Image in Page Properties Doesn't Apply a sling:resourceType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699233/aem-page-image-in-page-properties-doesnt-apply-a-slingresourcetype)